# Removing all null value fields on form submit in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi  all i'm using a Model driven form in my project on submit i get null value in my formGroupObj.value . I want to remove this fields which having null values .

My current  output is look like this.

```
{
   "firstName":"Jack",
   "lastName":"M",
   "age":null
}
```

My expecting output is

```
 {
    "firstName":"Jack",
    "lastName":"M"
 }
```

Is there any default way to get this out put?

Any one please help me.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think there is nothing like that out of the box for forms, you'd have to do something like mentioned in answers below.

Answer (score 8):

```js
var myObj = {
   "firstName":"Jack",
   "lastName":"M",
   "age":null,
   "someotherval": null
};

Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => (myObj[key] == null) && delete myObj[key]);
console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: I need to remove the blank values too so I do: ```Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => (myObj[key] === null || myObj[key] === '') && delete myObj[key]);```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myObj = {
   "firstName":"Jack",
   "lastName":"M",
   "age":null,
   "someotherval": null
};

for(key in myObj) {
  if(myObj[key] === null) {
    delete myObj[key];
  }
}

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

For **nested** objects (nested Form Groups), we need to use a recursive function:

```js
const myObj = {
  "name": {
    "firstName":"Jack",
    "lastName": null,
  },
  "age":null,
  "someotherval": "foo"
};

const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
     if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
       // recursive
       removeEmpty(obj[key]);
     } else if (obj[key] === null) {
       delete obj[key];
     }
   });
};

removeEmpty(myObj);
```

**Output:**

```js
const myObj = {
  "name": {
    "firstName":"Jack",
  },
  "someotherval": "foo"
};
```

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/xndbj3La/

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up andreivictor's answer and extended it to also remove an empty FormGroups.

```
removeEmpty = (obj: any) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    // recursive for FormGroups
    if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') this.removeEmpty(obj[key]);
    // null values
    if (obj[key] === null) delete obj[key];
    // empty objects - empty FormGroups
    if (JSON.stringify(obj[key]) === '{}') delete obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
};
```